# How to get the insrted row data in nodejs-mysql insert query?

Tags: mysql, node.js, insert

i have a simple insert query that looks like that:

```
let sql = "INSERT into users(name, date) VALUES ('"+name+"', '"+date+"')";
  connection.query(sql, (err, result) => {
      if(err) {
          res.status(500);
      } else {
        res.send(result) // we have here an object that has only the inserted id  
      }
  });
```

which i really want is getting the inserted row data not just the id without making another select query to get them.

is there is a way to make that happens in one query?

Comment: `mysql` doesnt return data on insert. You could use a query builder or an ORM http://knexjs.org/#Builder-returning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using:

`// include mysql module var mysql = require('mysql');`

The `mysql` module won't return data on the insert's query. It's returning:

- `Number of rows affected`, `Number of records affected with the warning`, `Message`

If you wanna get data that you inserted, you should use a query builder or ORM like Sequelize. [Sequelize Documentation](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/models-usage.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can get last inserted id using the code below:

```
SQLconnnection.query(sql, (err, result) => {
      if(err) {
          console.error(err);
      } else {
         console.log(result) ;
         /*Output=>{affectedRows: 1
                    changedRows: 0
                    fieldCount: 0
                    insertId: 1 =>Last inserted ID Here
                    message: ""
                    protocol41: true
                    serverStatus: 2
                    warningCount: 0}*/
       console.log(result.insertId);//=>last inserted id get
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to retrieve the

```
let sql = "INSERT into users(name, date) VALUES ('"+name+"', '"+date+"') ; SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
  connection.query(sql, (err, result) => {
      if(err) {
          res.status(500);
      } else {
        res.send(result) // we have here an object that has only the inserted id  
      }
  });
```

**SCOPE_IDENTITY()**  Returns the last identity value inserted